'The given account is owned by a different program than expected' trying to make a transaction, shows program error
I have written a contract where user can register as user and organisation and user can deploy sol to the organisation's address
I deployed it in Solana Playground and tried out the functions there and it is working. In Frontend integration too, the org and user registration is working. But when I try to deploy sol from user to wallet's address, I am facing error
This is the code
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { getProgram } from '../utils/anchor-client';
import { LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { web3, BN } from '@project-serum/anchor';

//// some other lines of code 

  const handleDeposit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!wallet.publicKey) return;

    const program = getProgram(connection, wallet);
    try {
      await program.methods.depositSol(new BN(parseFloat(amount) * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL))
        .accounts({
          userAccount: wallet.publicKey,
          user: wallet.publicKey,
          platform: new PublicKey(orgAddress),
          systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc();
      console.log("SOL deposited successfully");
      onClose();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error depositing SOL:", error);
    }
  };

This is the error I am getting
DepositSol.tsx:36 Error depositing SOL: 
Error: AnchorError caused by account: user_account. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.
Program log: Left:
Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Program log: Right:
Program log: {My ProgramID i have hidden}
    at AnchorError.parse (index.js:1277:20)
    at translateError (index.js:1361:37)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (index.js:5002:23)
    at async handleDeposit (DepositSol.tsx:25:7)

Although, in my anchor-utils.ts, I have given the ProgramID which is mentioned here in Right...
Any solutions?

Can you provide the program code? Looks like it is expecting your userAccount to be some kind of PDA derived from your program, and you're passing in a system account
